# Facebook javascript ui to post to wall, page or message?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

I've managed to get the share button to work but it does not format the post correctly for each image, so I tried the FB.ui method, but that only seems to allow me to post to my own wall??? Am I completely not getting the FB Api?? The documentation pretty much SUCKS on developer facebook page...

```
var fbConfig = {
            method: 'feed',
            display: 'popup',
            name: scope.content.post.post_title,
            link: scope.link,
            picture: scope.content.image.src,
            caption: scope.content.post.post_title + ' is featured on The Sexiest Non Profit Ever\'s website',
            // description: 'a slightly longer description...',
            // redirect_uri: 'http://www.thesexiestnonprofitever.org/'
        };

FB.ui(fbConfig, function(response){

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Take `publish_stream` permission to post on other's wall. Without this permission you cannot post any thing on the other's wall. This is necessary